# grub2 and cryptsetup

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, luks

My root node is LUKS encrypted, and it uses a key file, instead of user input password to unlock it.

I know in Grub2, I can use

```
insmod cryptodisk
insmod luks
cryptomount -u <uuid>
```

But I have no idea how to use a key file to unlock the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
insmod (hd0,1)/routeto/keyfile.file
```

change **(hd0,1)** (if necessary)and put the mounting point of the keyfile file system, sda or whatsoever...